# Kotlin - assigning non-nullable type to nullable type

Tags: kotlin, nullable

I am assigning a value to val nullable type from null-able string. Getting un-expected results. The code is as follows:

```
val username3: String? = null       // null assigned to constant. can be re-assigned after a check.
    if (name2 != null) {
        val username3 = name2           // no error, statement execute and username3 remains null? is it a bug?
    }
    System.out.format("3) name2: %s, username3: %s%n", name2, username3)
```

Result is:
3) name2: Jamie Smith, username3: null

Comment: Name shadowing.

Answer (score 2):

`val username3 = name2` statement defines a new variable `username3` and sets its value to `name2`. It's not the same `username3` that you defined in the first line. New `username3`'s scope is only within if condition.

1) If you want to assign value to a variable at later stage then define it with `var` not `val`.

2) when you put `var`/`val` before variable name you define a new variable. Don't do this when you want to assign value to already defined variable.